# Parse date string in RFC 2822 format (as found in HTTP header field `last-modified`)

Tags: javascript, date, node.js

I'm using Node.js . In a HTTP response header is a field `last-modified` with a string representing a date and time according to [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3)

```
 'last-modified': 'Tue, 27 Dec 2011 02:12:35 GMT',
```

How do I convert this to a Javascript Date object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's wrong with the JS Date methods?

```
new Date( 'Tue, 27 Dec 2011 02:12:35 GMT' )
```

Comment: You're right. Thanks. What I wanted was a Unix timestamp, and I found `Date.parse(''Tue, 27 Dec 2011 02:12:35 GMT')/1000` works for that.